# MAR10 Day Puzzle: What character am I?

Tags: riddle, cipher, video-games

In honor of MAR10 day, I have created a puzzle for you! Try to guess what Mario universe character I am, and what game I'm from.

```
R ad to
         k   ar
 l     thi v?  of s y  a  e 
    h to the s      fl? er f   d
 e       e        ll

The     ' ound the c    r
  ?  i  ???  ? ?   r?? ?
```

Hint:

> The red herring you might come across is indeed a red herring, but it has a connection to the answer. You'll see what I mean later.

Hint 2:

> `We can  oo  a l the   y t      ???? f  m   is g   t  i e    ky w r`

Hint 3:

> Does anyone want to **edit** my question?

Hint 4:

> Go to the tinyurl url with the characters that would be where the question marks are. That's tinyurl.com/???????????

Hint 5:

> 160500643816367088 259695496911122585 420196140727489673 679891637638612258

Comment: Looks like a railroad cipher to me

Comment: Is he/she a well known mario character?

Comment: @North The "first stage" (the text above) is not a cipher. The character is pretty well known, and if you played a Mario game before, you probably would have seen one.

Comment: Ummm then why is there a cipher tag

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE btw

Comment: @North the puzzle has many stages. The first stage will lead you somewhere else, maybe that place will have a cipher? ;-)

Comment: hmm, I guess I know the overall flow to solve the puzzle but... I haven't even solved the first stage :( (I guess we need to feel the blanks with letters, get a full paragraph, then will know what are the `?`s stand for).

Comment: number of spaces represent number of missing letters? so, c____r can be cipher?

Comment: @smriti, yes it could be.. but i think it's rather...... impossible (?) to find the full paragraph with given info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, since there weren't many answers I guess I'll post the correct solution.

## First clue: Block with missing letters

> Each line of the block is the name of a Power Moon from the Wooded Kingdom, from *Super Mario Odyssey*. They correspond to the fibonacci numbers, so I have added numbers before each line.

1:

> `Road to Sky Garden`

1:

> `Road to Sky Garden`

2:

> `Flower Thieves of Sky Garden`

3:

> `Path to the Secret Flower Field`

5:

> `Behind the Rock Wall`

8:

> `Caught Hopping in the Forest!`

13:

> `The Nut 'Round the Corner`

21:

> `Love in the Forest Ruins`

Filling in the question marks, that gives you:

> eovtheouis

telling you to go to:

> tinyurl.com/eovtheouis

## Second clue: The Pastebin

The url takes you to [a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mn7k199D) with the text:

> `64 01,000.0100.01.000.0000,0110.1001.0001.10.011,011.0000.0.010.0,0110,01.10.100,011,01.010.0,1010.01.0110.00.1.01.0100`

Which means:

> The `64` just hints that the character is from *Super Mario 64*. The 0s and 1s are not binary, but they are morse, where `0` corresponds to a `.` and `1` corresponds to a `-`. The `.`s translate to spaces to denote new characters, and the `,`s denote a new word.

That gives you:

> `.- / ... .-.. .- ... .... / .--. -..- ...- -. .-- / .-- .... . .-. . / .--. / .- -. -.. / .-- / .- .-. . / -.-. .- .--. .. - .- .-..`

If you translate that, you get:

> A SLASH PXVNW WHERE P AND W ARE CAPITAL

Which means:

> a/PxvnW

You can now use that in an

> [imgur url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLU2A.jpg)

giving you the image:

> [image: Solution Image]

which is a

> Bub from SM64! These are known as Cheep-Cheeps from other games.

## Hints

### 1

> This was referring to the Bub/Cheep Cheep. They are usually red, and a fish, so this was an interesting hint.

### 2

This is another one of the incomplete text things. If you fill in the missing letters, you get:

> `We can zoom all the way to the MOON from this great wide wacky world`

You might recognize this from:

> The lyrics of "Jump Up, Super Star!" the "main theme" of Super Mario Odyssey. The question marks here represented "moon," hinting at having to find power moon names.

### 3

This hint tells you to

> edit the question.

If you do, you'll find:

> that I hid [HTML Comment Tags](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp) in the source (which is accessed through editing).

They say:

1.

> The smallest universal resource locator, hinting at tinyurl

2.

> Imgur, telling you to use Imgur

3.

> Misty Groves, hinting at Steam Gardens, another name for the Wooded Kingdom

### 4

This one is straightforward. You just have to do what it asks you to do.

### 5

These are some

> Fibonacci Numbers

telling you that you will use them.

Comment: Actually, this is a great puzzle ^^. My two cents: 1. Filling the missing letters is not that simple, they are not google-able and there are too many possibilities to try; you may make it easier or give a hint for that (even filling the missing letters on the hint part is hard IMHO). 2. It's only 2 days since your question was posted. Beside answering your question, you may give another additional hints or put a bounty to gain more attention, ofc if you want to. Anyway, thanks for the nice puzzle!